# Show that $\limsup_{s,\:t\:\to\:\tau}\left\|x(s)-x(t)\right\|_E\ge r$ implies $\left\|\Delta x(\tau)\right\|_E\ge r$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, stochastic-analysis

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, and $x:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be right-continuous. Assume $x$ $$x(t-):=\lim_{s\to t-}x(s)$$ exists for all $t\in O$ and let $$\Delta x(t):=x(t)-x(t-)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0.$$

> Let $\tau\ge0$ and $r>0$ with $$\ell:=\limsup_{s,\:t\:\to\:\tau}\left\|x(s)-x(t)\right\|_E\ge r\tag1.$$ How can we conclude that $\left\|x(\tau)\right\|_E\ge r$?

Intuitively, this should be easy to verify, but I'm unable to prove it rigorously. Since we can show that the assumptions imply that $x$ is bounded on each compact interval, we've clearly got $\ell<\infty$. From this we can deduce that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ with $$\left\|x(s)-x(t)\right\|_E<\ell+\varepsilon\tag2$$ for all $s,t\ge0$ with $\max(|s-\tau|,|t-\tau|)<\delta$. In particular, $$\left\|x(\tau)-x(t)\right\|_E<\ell+\varepsilon\tag3$$ for all $t\in(\tau-\delta,\tau)$.

On the other hand, we have $$\left\|\Delta x(\tau)\right\|_E=\lim_{t\to\tau-}\left\|x(\tau)-x(t)\right\|_E\tag4$$ and hence there is a $\tilde\delta$ with $$\left|\left\|x(\tau)-x(t)\right\|_E-\left\|\Delta x(\tau)\right\|_E\right|<\varepsilon\tag5$$ for all $t\in(\tau-\delta\tilde,\tau)$.

But how can we conclude?

Comment: In “How can we conclude that $\left\|x(\tau)\right\|_E\ge r$?” you probably mean $\left\| \Delta x(\tau)\right\|_E\ge r$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $d = \Vert \Delta x(\tau)\Vert < r$. Choose $\epsilon > 0$ so small that $d + 2\epsilon < r$.

From $x(\tau-) =\lim_{s\to \tau-}x(s)$ it follows that there is an $\delta_1 > 0$ such that
$$
 \forall x \in (\tau - \delta_1, \tau]:  \Vert x(s) - x(\tau-) \Vert < \epsilon \, ,
$$
and from the right continuity it follows that that there is an $\delta_2 > 0$ such that
$$
 \forall x \in [\tau, \tau + \delta_2):  \Vert x(s) - x(\tau) \Vert < \epsilon \, .
$$

Now let $s, t \in (\tau-\delta_1, \tau + \delta_2)$. We have to consider three cases:

1. If both $s$ and $t$ are $\le \tau$ then
   $$
    \Vert x(s) - x(t)\Vert \le \Vert x(s) - x(\tau-)\Vert + \Vert x(\tau-) - x(t)\Vert < 2 \epsilon \, .
   $$
2. If both $s$ and $t$ are $\ge \tau$ then also
   $$
    \Vert x(s) - x(t)\Vert \le \Vert x(s) - x(\tau)\Vert + \Vert x(\tau) - x(t)\Vert < 2 \epsilon \, .
   $$
3. If $s < \tau < t$ then
   $$
   \Vert x(s) - x(t)\Vert \le \Vert x(s) - x(\tau-)\Vert + \Vert x(\tau-) - x(\tau)\Vert + \Vert x(\tau) - x(t)\Vert < d+2 \epsilon \, .
   $$

So in any case we have
$$ 
\Vert x(s) - x(t)\Vert <d +2\epsilon
$$
for all $s, t \in (\tau-\delta_1, \tau + \delta_2)$, and it follows that
$$
r \le \ell = \limsup_{s, t \to \tau} \Vert x(s) - x(t)\Vert  \le d +2\epsilon < r \, 
$$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be easier to argue the contrapositive: $\left\|\Delta x\left(\tau\right)\right\|_E < r$ implies that $\limsup_{s,t \to \tau} \left\|x(s) - x(t)\right\|_E < r$.

We suppose that $\left\|\Delta x\left(\tau\right)\right\|_E < r$. In particular that implies that there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ and a $R> 0$ such that
$$\ \left\|x\left(\tau\right) - x\left(s\right)\right\|_E \leq r - \varepsilon$$
for all $s < \tau$ such that $\tau - s < R$.
Secondly, as $x$ is right continuous, there exists a $R' > 0$ such that
$$ \left\|x\left(\tau\right) - x\left(t\right)\right\|_E < \varepsilon/2 $$
for all $t \geq \tau$ such that $t- \tau < R'$. This implies that if $s,t \in \left]\tau - R, \tau + R'\right[$,
$$\left\|x(s)-x(t)\right\|_E \leq \left\|x(s) - x(\tau)\right\|_E + \left\|x(s) - x(\tau)\right\|_E < r - \varepsilon/2 < r.$$
From this inequality we may conclude that
$$\limsup_{s,t \to \tau} \left\|x(s) - x(t)\right\|_E < r.$$

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. I wasn't able to come back to this problem until now. Thank you for your answer, but please note that something is wrong in how you intend to conclude. First of all, one of the $s$'s should be a $t$ in your third centered equation. More crucial: It seems like you're assuming $s\in(\tau-R,\tau)$ and $t\in(\tau,\tau+R')$, since otherwise you cannot use the inequalities you've shown before.